# PHP - RecursiveArrayIterator recurse on all but last level

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, iterator

I need to flatten a multidimensional array, but not flattening the last level.

For example, consider the following array

```
$array = [
    1 => [
        1 => [
            'anna',
            'alice'
        ],
        2 => [
            'bob',
            'bartold'
        ]
    ],
    2 => [
        1 => [
            'carol'
        ],
        2 => [
            'david'
        ]
    ]
];
```

The following code

```
$result = [];

$iterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new \RecursiveArrayIterator($array)
);

foreach ($iterator as $row) {
    $result[] = $row;
}
```

returns the following array

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "anna"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "alice"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "bob"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "bartold"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "carol"
  [5]=>
  string(5) "david"
}
```

What I would like to obtain is the following:

```
[
    1 => [
        'anna',
        'alice'
    ],
    2 => [
        'bob',
        'bartold'
    ],
    3 => [
        'carol'
    ],
    4 => [
        'david'
    ]
];
```

not flattening the last level of the array.
Is there an easy way to obtain this?

Possibly I would like to use iterators.

If you want you could try to play with [this](http://3v4l.org/RoOVf#v540).

Comment: did you try with array_walk_recursive? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php

Comment: @briosheje yes, I tried, the result is exactly the same as the one that I get with the code I posted

Comment: You can't get what you want for two reasons: 1) The nesting logic of the node [1] is different from node [2]. 2) you're somehow assigning new keys that cannot be logically recreated in a recursive loop (keys 1,2,3,4 in the output), because it is recursive. I would personally suggest you to either perform a nested foreach loop or to just implement an ad-hoc function.

Answer (score 2):

You can flatten the array recursively while on each element you would **look ahead** if it contains subarrays and change merging based on it:

```
<?php

function flattenArrayWithLookAhead($include = array()) {
  $new = array();

  foreach($include as $item) {
    if(is_array($item)) {
      $containsArrays = array_reduce($item, function ($carry, $current) {
        if(is_array($current) || $carry === true) return true;
        else return false;
      });

      if($containsArrays) $new = array_merge($new, flattenArrayWithLookAhead($item));
      else $new[] = $item;
    } else {
      $new[] = $item;
    }
  }

  return $new;
}

$array = flattenArrayWithLookAhead($array);
```

[online TEST](https://eval.in/314395)

(NOTE: I'm sure the function can be simplified but my love for recursive functions is currently at its minimum.)

Answer (score 1):

Remember that recursive iterators always walk the data structure to return the **data nodes**, not the preceding structure. To keep the structure as well you could do a nested `foreach`

```
$newdata = array();
foreach($data as $group) {
    foreach($group as $set) {
        $newdata[] = $set;
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem with the nested foreach is that if I need to add a nesting level near the root, my code would not work anymore. I guess that the only solution would be to use a recursive function